# multiselect pick list custom field

Tags: formula, multi-select, if, isblank, include

I have a long if(includes formula that is aggregating a few common responses into the same text values. (It's longer than below but that is enough for my question). There are actually 3 outcomes I want:

1. Replacing the text as indicated
2. leaving blanks blank
3. aggregating everything else into 'reported outside of selections'.

I have 1 and 2 covered. How do I get everything else (where there is a value) to be relabeled?

```
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Indigenous"),"Indigenous or Native;",null)& 
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"white european"),"White or Anglo;",null)& 
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Indígena"),"Indigenous or Native",null)& 
if(isblank(Race_or_Ethnicity__c),null,null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this for the third scenario:

```
  IF(

      AND
      (
      NOT(INCLUDES(Race_or_Ethnicity__c, 'Indigenous')),

      NOT(INCLUDES(Race_or_Ethnicity__c, 'white european')),

      NOT(INCLUDES(Race_or_Ethnicity__c, 'Indígena')),

      NOT(ISBLANK(Race_or_Ethnicity__c))
      )
    ,
     'reported outside of selections'
    ,
      null
  )
```